# How can I use pandas to output a specific column based on a user inputting another column?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, input

I'm trying to create a python script using pandas where it prompts the user for a value from column `'Name'(or column 0)` and then prints the value in column `'Location'(or column 9)`.

So far I have the following but it prints all columns in the row. How can I make it print a specific column?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Servers.csv")
user_input = raw_input("Enter server name: ")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[0] == user_input:
        print row
```

I would like to only have it print the 9th column from the row `labled 'Location'` when I enter a value from the first column `labled 'Name'`.

Currently it's printing all columns in the row when I enter a value from the first column `Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a loop here, construct a series and then query the series via [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.at.html). This assumes you do not have duplicate names.

```
df = pd.read_csv("Servers.csv")
series_map = df.set_index('Name')['Location']
user_input = raw_input("Enter server name: ")

print series_map.at[user_input]
```

---

The problem with your loop method is you don't index `row`, you can just use:

```
print row[9]
```

Comment: Thank you jpp! That worked perfectly. Sorry, I'm a newb and can't upvote yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line `print(df[df['Name'] == user_input].loc[:,'Location'].values[0])` should do the trick.

Here's a simple example with a dataframe containing 3 rows and columns:

```
d = {'Name': ['John', 'Laura', 'Sam'], 
     'Food': ['Sushi', 'Spaghetti', 'Sandwich'], 
     'Location': ['Houston', 'San Francisco', 'Hawaii']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

    Name    Food        Location
0   John    Sushi       Houston
1   Laura   Spaghetti   San Francisco
2   Sam     Sandwich    Hawaii
```

If `user_input = 'John'`, here's how we print out his location:

`print(df[df['Name'] == user_input].loc[:,'Location'].values[0])`

Which will output the string `Houston`.

This approach avoids loops and should be faster than using .iterrows().